# SSRS Print one row then detail

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have a report that has two sections of data.  In a list component with textboxes I have Barcode, warehouse location, pallets. Then below this I have detail information in a tablix including Racklocation Use by date, Qty, Product, Description, PalletID, Customer Product and Weight.  How do I print one barcode row then detail for that shipment, then page break? Then same again for next row?  Thanks i'm really banging my head with this one!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing was using the lookup function for EACH item I needed to lookup referencing unique value i.e. pickrouteID to then lookup what i needed.  Example

=Lookup(Fields!.Value, Fields!.Value, Fields!.Value, "containing dataset")

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you just want there to be a page break after each of your packing slips? If so select the list, then at the bottom of the window where it says "Row Groups" right click the first group and go to "Group Properties". Finally, go to the "Page Breaks" window and click "Between each instance of a group" and then "Also at the end of a group". That should do it.

Comment: Hi Dan, yes except I want print the barcode, detail then a page break.  I also need to group the barcode detail with the row detail which is what i'm stuck on...

Comment: Is your tablix with the Racklocation, Use by date etc actually within the list itself? If not, move it to be inside the list directly below your barcode and other textboxes. Provided the List is grouped on something (probably the order number in your case) this should work fine, and should keep both items together.

Comment: Hi Dan yes I thought about this.  But you can only reference one dataset in a list I believe.  I think the answer to this is to use lookupset function?  If I can figure out how to use lookupset to combine the barcode detail but then I'll need to assign it to a row...

Comment: Yes, LookUps are your friend here. Woops Pressed submit by mistake; give me 5 mins I'm editing the reply.

Comment: Tch, 5 minutes passed so can't edit now. Yes, LookUps are your friend here. I don't think you can generate rows in a table with LookUpSet though, so you'd maybe have to base the List and Matrix on the dataset with that data and use LookUps to fetch the data for the TextBoxes and Barcode. If that doesn't help, can you upload the report somewhere?

Comment: Hi post your email, I'll send to you... can you delete your email off this after?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65135/discussion-between-dan-scally-and-jhowe).